# Matlab, Matrix-Division. Showing multile results / non trivial result

Tags: matlab, division

I have a 5x5 Matrix A:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">-4</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">0</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">0</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">1</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">0</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">-5</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">-6</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">-6</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">-6</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and want to find a vector x:

A*x = 0.

The only way I can think of is by left division in matlab. This gives a trivial result for x: x = [0 0 0 0 0].

Anyhow, in this case i want the result:

x = [1 0 -1 4 -0.25]

does someone know how I can get this?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [`null`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function. But it doesn't give the exact answer without some transformations:

```
x = -null(A,'r')/4
```

Seems to work.